# Im trying to use an eventListener but it doesnt actually listen to my form's submit button. Can someone identify whats wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

My html (im using codepen)

```
<div name= "calculoConsumo">
  
  <div name = "velocimetroQTDlitros">
    
  </div> 
  <div name = "velocimetroDistanciaViagem">
    
  </div> 
  
  <form>

  <input type = "text" id="001" name="inputCarro" placeholder = "Qtd Litros " ></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type = "text" id="002" name="inputLitros" placeholder = "Distancia da viagem " ></input>
   <br><br>
<button type = "submit" id="003" > Enviar </button>

</form>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.calculoConsumo {
  text-allign: center;
  text-color: blue;
  border-radius: 15% ;
background-color: gray ;
}
.velocimetroQTDlitros, velocimetroDistanciaViagem{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
```

My broken JS:

```
try{
  async exec(){
      let Litros;
      let Distancia;
      let Consumo;

     function inputLitros(001){ 
       to.selectById('001'){
        function ()
         this.Litros;
      };
     }
    function inputDistancia(002){
      to.selectById('002'){
        this.Distancia;
      };

     }
      Consumo = Distancia/ Litros;
   add.eventListener(001, inputLitros);
   add.eventListener(002, inputDistancia);
    alert.("Seu Consumo é:", Consumo);
  }
}
 catch(error){
   return error;
 }
```

My attempt is to create a gas consume calculator. It will listen to my html form and peform a calculation.

My expectation was that  once you clicked on "enviar"( submit) the values answered would pass as parameters in inputLitros and inputDistancia and then these values were going to be setted in "Litros" (liters) and "Distancia" (distance) so i could achieve "Consumo" (consume).
Consumo would then be alerted on the navigator

Comment: There's no call to `addEventListener()` in your code.

Comment: You have `add.eventListener()`, but you never declared the variable `add`. And `to.selectById()` but you never declared `to`.

Comment: `async exec()` is not the correct way to define a function. It should be `async function exec()`. But there's no need for this to be `async`, it never uses `await`.

Comment: You add an event listener with `element.addEventListener("eventname", function)`. Where `element` is a variable holding the element you want to attach the event listener to. There's so much wrong here that you need to go back to a tutorial and learn the basics.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code has a lot of syntax problems and missing variables and other issues; I'm sorry to say that there are too many issues to start helping out with it. For example, what is the `to` variable?